# Admin table not populating with DB information

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I have an admin table that I trying to retrieve information from MySQL DB for the admins to edit. When I run the application the table shows up but no information is populating the table. Below is my admin.jsp page.

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style1.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/css; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>admin</title>
<script language="javascript">
function editRecord(id){

    window.location.href="editServlet/"+id; 
  }


  function deleteRecord(id){

    window.location.href="deleteUser/"+id; 
  }
</script>

</head>

<body>

 <div class="content">


 <br>
<table align="center">

</table>
<br>
  <table width="600px"  align="center" style="background-color:#EDF6EA;border:1px solid #000000;">
 <tr><td colspan=9 align="center" height="10px"></td></tr>


<tr><td colspan=9 align="center" height="10px"></td></tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#7BA88B;font-weight:bold;">
     <td>CourseID</td><td>Course Rate</td><td>Professor</td>
     <td>Professor Rate</td><td>Review</td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td>
  </tr>
    <%
    String bgcolor="";
    int count=0;
    List viewList = new ArrayList();
    Iterator  viewItr;

    if(request.getAttribute("courseList")!=null && request.getAttribute("courseList")!="")
    {
        List courseList =  (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("courseList");
        Iterator itr = courseList.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {

            if(count%2==0)
            {
             bgcolor = "#C8E2D1";
            }
            else
            {

                bgcolor = "#EAF8EF";
            }

            viewList = (ArrayList)itr.next();
            int id = Integer.parseInt(viewList.get(0).toString());
            viewItr = viewList.iterator();
            %>
            <tr style="background-color:<%=bgcolor%>;">
            <%  
            while(viewItr.hasNext())
            {

                %>
                <td><%=viewItr.next()%></td>

                <%

            }
            count++;
            %>
            <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;" onclick="editRecord(<%=id%>);" ></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="delete" style="background-color:#ff0000;font-weight:bold;;color:#ffffff;" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRecord(<%=id%>);"></td>
            </tr>
            <%
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
    {
        %>
        <tr><td colspan="9" align="center">&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="9" align="center">No Record Avaliable</td></tr>
        <%
    }
    %>
     <tr><td colspan=9 align="center" height="2px"></td></tr>
  </table>  


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my one of my servlets:

```
package com.admin;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CourseServlet extends HttpServlet{ 

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                                   throws ServletException,IOException{
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String str[] = request.getRequestURI().toString().split("/");

         int id = Integer.parseInt(str[3]);
            Connection conn = null;
            String DB_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase";
            String DB_USERNAME = "";
            String DB_PASSWORD = "";

        //  out.println(request.getRequestURI());
            Statement st;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION_URL, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
                System.out.println("Connected to the database");

                ArrayList<Comparable> courseList=null;
                String query = "select * from coursereview where id="+id;
                System.out.println("query " + query);
                st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet  rs = st.executeQuery(query);


                while(rs.next())
                {

                  courseList =new ArrayList<Comparable>();
                  courseList.add(rs.getInt(1));
                  courseList.add(rs.getString(2));
                  courseList.add(rs.getString(4));
                  courseList.add(rs.getString(5));
                  courseList.add(rs.getString(6));
                  courseList.add(rs.getString(7));


                }

                request.setAttribute("courseList",courseList);

                String nextJSP = "/editUser.jsp";
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
                dispatcher.forward(request,response);
                conn.close();
                System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
  }
}
```

Here is my Servlet record:

```
package com.admin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletRecord extends HttpServlet{ 

   /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7311509570234925786L;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                                   throws ServletException,IOException{
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
            Connection conn = null;
            String DB_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase";
            String DB_USERNAME = "";
            String DB_PASSWORD = "";


            Statement st;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION_URL, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
                System.out.println("Connected to the database");

                ArrayList<Comparable> al=null;
                ArrayList<ArrayList<Comparable>> courseList =new ArrayList<ArrayList<Comparable>>();
                String query = "select * from coursereview order by id";
                System.out.println("query " + query);
                st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet  rs = st.executeQuery(query);


                while(rs.next())
                {
                    al  = new ArrayList<Comparable>();

                  al.add(rs.getInt(1));
                  al.add(rs.getString(2));
                  al.add(rs.getString(4));
                  al.add(rs.getString(5));
                  al.add(rs.getString(6));
                  al.add(rs.getString(7));
                  al.add(rs.getString(8));
                 System.out.println("al :: "+al);
                  courseList.add(al);
                }

                request.setAttribute("courseList",courseList);

                String nextJSP = "/admin.jsp";
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
                dispatcher.forward(request,response);
                conn.close();
                System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
  }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a lot of code to shift through and you have not provided us with any pointers as to where things may go south. You need to do some debugging and narrow the code down.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include just enough to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)